# How to form the i j k variables of 'for loop' to a new matrix?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, variables, matrix

```
for i = [1:1:7]
    for j = [1:1:8]
        for k= [1,2]
            expression = 5*i+6*j-2*k;   % just for example
            matrix(i,j,k) = expression;
        end
    end
end
```

I want to make the results display more intuitive, that is, the variables and the results are associated with the same form. when got a value in the result, i can find its corresponding 'i j k' coordinate quickly, that's what i want.

Combine i j k into a matrix:
[image: Combine i j k into a matrix]

Is there any way to achieve this form?

Comment: Please improve your question by reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to create a matrix that contains 3 values in each element?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes，that's what i want.

Comment: So maybe you want a 4-dimensional numeric array? Or a 3-dimensional array where each element is a cell array either containing a vector of three numbers or containing three scalar (1x1) numbers?  It's not clear how any of this would help with "making the results display more intuitive", or what the problem you're really trying to solve is.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to do it creating a 3 dimension matrix before you enter the function, then you can print it.

`

```
mat = zeros(7,8,2)
for i = 1:7
    for j = 1:8
        for k= [1,2]
            expression = 5*i+6*j-2*k;   % just for example
            mat(i,j,k) = expression;
        end
    end
end
mat
```

`